# button action touchup inside doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

viewcontroller.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<kDropDownListViewDelegate>
 {
 NSArray *arryList;
 NSArray *arryList1;
 DropDownListView * Dropobj;
 }

- (IBAction)DropDownPressed:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)DropDownPressed1:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblSelectedCountryNames;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblSelectedCountryNames1;
@end
```

viewcontroller.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

[super viewDidLoad];


arryList=@[@"India",@"Swaziland",@"Africa",@"Australlia",@"Pakistan"];


arryList1=@[@"India1",@"Swaziland1",@"Africa1",@"Australlia1",@"Pakistan"];    

}
 - (void)DropDownListView:(DropDownListView *)dropdownListView didSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex
{
/*----------------Get Selected Value[Single selection]-----------------*/
    _lblSelectedCountryNames.text=[arryList objectAtIndex:anIndex];
    _lblSelectedCountryNames1.text=[arryList1 objectAtIndex:anIndex];

}
 - (IBAction)DropDownPressed:(id)sender 
{
[Dropobj fadeOut];
[self showPopUpWithTitle:@"Select Country" withOption:arryList xy:CGPointMake(16, 58)     size:CGSizeMake(287, 330) isMultiple:NO];
}
- (IBAction)DropDownPressed1:(id)sender 
{
[Dropobj fadeOut];
[self showPopUpWithTitle:@"Select " withOption:arryList1 xy:CGPointMake(16, 58)     size:CGSizeMake(287, 330) isMultiple:NO];
}
```

onclick the DropDownPressed1 it doesn't load with the arrylist1....instead of that it loads with the arrylist...and if i select the valaue example india....that's the value shown in both the labels.....how to correct those problems...if it's not clear give ur mailid ..i will send my sample project thanks in advance...

Comment: Check the connection of `DropDownPressed1` and `DropDownPressed`. Did you try to debug?

Comment: if i click both the button action pressed ...same arrylist gets loaded and if i select the values ....similar values will be displayed in both the labels..how to populate the correct arraylist and displaying the correct values in labels.

Comment: Are you sure it go into both DropDownPressed1 and DropDownPressed?

Comment: @ anhtu yeah i checked the connection... now it's correctly loaded but now onclick the dropdownpressed if i selects india...it automatically shows in  _lblSelectedCountryNames1 also..how to avoid this...

Comment: `- (void)DropDownListView:(DropDownListView *)dropdownListView didSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex
{
/*----------------Get Selected Value[Single selection]-----------------*/
    _lblSelectedCountryNames.text=[arryList objectAtIndex:anIndex];
    _lblSelectedCountryNames1.text=[arryList1 objectAtIndex:anIndex];

}`  modify this function as you want. You can use 1 var to check, if you tap on DropDownPressed1 or DropDownPressed.

Comment: I will post an answer for this.

Comment: DropDownListView: dropdownListView:atIndex check this method with break poits

Answer (score 0):

For more buttons and labels :

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController<kDropDownListViewDelegate>
     {
     NSArray *arryList;
     NSArray *arryList1;
     DropDownListView * Dropobj;

     int iTappedBtn;
     }


    - (void)DropDownListView:(DropDownListView *)dropdownListView didSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex
    {
    /*----------------Get Selected Value[Single selection]-----------------*/
         switch (iTappedBtn){
           case 0:
           {
            _lblSelectedCountryNames.text=[arryList objectAtIndex:anIndex];
           } 
           case 1: 
           {
            _lblSelectedCountryNames1.text=[arryList1 objectAtIndex:anIndex];
           }
           // and so on: 
           // case ...
         }
    }
     - (IBAction)DropDownPressed:(id)sender 
    {
    iTappedBtn = 0;

    [Dropobj fadeOut];
    [self showPopUpWithTitle:@"Select Country" withOption:arryList xy:CGPointMake(16, 58)     size:CGSizeMake(287, 330) isMultiple:NO];
    }
    - (IBAction)DropDownPressed1:(id)sender 
    {
    iTappedBtn = 1;

    [Dropobj fadeOut];
    [self showPopUpWithTitle:@"Select " withOption:arryList1 xy:CGPointMake(16, 58)     size:CGSizeMake(287, 330) isMultiple:NO];
    }
    // and so on for other DropDownPressed
```

This isn't really good. But simple to understand.

Comment: yeah bro it works fine...how can i check for i am having three labels....and one more thing.....for the value selected in dropdownpressed values to be changed in dropdownpressed1 and dropdownpressed2.....but i select values in dropdownpressed1  value to be changed in dropdownpressed1 only it won't change others..how to do it..bro

Comment: I don't understand all your question. But I will edit my answer again.

Comment: yeah everything works fine ......i have one doubt...or need...if i click the dropdownpressed1....values should be changed in that only not in dropdownpressed2... is it possible..means..how to do it?

Comment: case 1: 
           {_lblSelectedCountryNames.text=[arryList1 objectAtIndex:anIndex];
            _lblSelectedCountryNames1.text=[arryList1 objectAtIndex:anIndex];
           }

Comment: You can use switch case to do what you want